# Prevent color overlapping when the border-radius property is used

Tags: html, css

I have the following simple markup:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="one"></div>
    <div class="two"></div>
</div>
```

And this CSS:

```
.wrapper {
    position: relative;
    width: 250px; 
    height: 250px;
}

.wrapper .one,
.wrapper .two {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    border: 20px solid;
    border-radius: 100%;
}

.wrapper .one {
    border-color: red;
}

.wrapper .two {
    border-color: yellow;
}
```

When I preview the page in a browser, I see this result:
[image]

What I want is to get rid of the red color that appears as an outline. If I remove the `border-radius` property the problem doesn't exist.

Is there any clever solution for preventing this overlapping and showing only the border color of the `.two` element? Note that I don't want to remove any border colors.

One possible solution might be to use a darker color instead of the yellow one. But, it doesn't seem like the perfect solution.

Anyhow, here's what I want:

[image]

Comment: Not really, this is a common problem due to subpixel rounding...